# Applying a function to a list based on an ID

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have two list, and from those I would like to find the averages between different combinations of elements. I would like to find the mean based on the `ID` names between the list.

For example:
I would like to find the means between `ID` "A" in list `l1` and `l2`.

I would like to calculate the mean between the first `B` in `l1` and `l2`, then the second `B` in `l1` and l2`.

I would like to calculate the mean between the first `C` in `l1` and `l2`, then the second `C` in `l1` and l2`. Then the third` C`in`l1`and`l2`.

In my actual list, I have an extensive number of elements in each list so a more autonomous method is preferred.

```
l1 <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6)
names(l1) <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C","C")

l2 <- list(7,8,9,10,11,12)
names(l2) <- c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C","C")

# A
mean(c(l1[[1]], l2[[1]]))

#B
mean(c(l1[[2]], l2[[2]]))
mean(c(l1[[2]], l2[[3]]))

#B
mean(c(l1[[3]], l2[[2]]))
mean(c(l1[[3]], l2[[3]]))

# C
mean(c(l1[[4]], l2[[4]]))
mean(c(l1[[4]], l2[[5]]))
mean(c(l1[[4]],l2[[6]]))

# C
mean(c(l1[[5]], l2[[4]]))
mean(c(l1[[5]], l2[[5]]))
mean(c(l1[[5]],l2[[6]]))

# C
mean(c(l1[[6]], l2[[4]]))
mean(c(l1[[6]], l2[[5]]))
mean(c(l1[[6]],l2[[6]]))
```

Comment: Are the list of same size and have same names in that order?

Comment: Yes, they are the same order and same names.

Comment: `a<-lapply(list(l1, l2),\(x)split(unlist(x), names(x)));Map(\(x,y)rowMeans(expand.grid(x, y)), a[[2]], a[[1]])`

Comment: If I wanted to change the function used on the lists, how would I go about modifying this?

Comment: @Onyambu can you post this as an answer?